# When to use -f and -z in shell IF condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I know that if a variable is empty, -z can be used in `IF` condition.
I am unable to differentiate following conditions in Unix shell.

```
a=   <empty>

if [ -z $a ]; then echo 1; else echo 2; fi
```

> --> gives 1

```
if [ -f $a ]; then echo 1; else echo 2; fi
```

> --> gives 1

So could please tell me the when to use -f and -z ?

Comment: have you tried `man test` or `man [` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl: I just checked it. `-f means file exist check` `-z for variable empty check`. Am i correct ?

Comment: Yes, probably you were searching for `-n` which checks that the string is *not* empty

Comment: @hek2mgl unfortunately `[ -n $a ]` without quotes will also be true for the same reason as I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @TomFenech Yes, you got my up ;) Quoting is essential here! I just wanted to find out what OP wants...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some double quotes! If `$a` is not set, `[ -f $a ]` is equivalent to `[ -f ]`, which doesn't do anything more than test that `-f` is a non-empty string. On the other hand `[ -f "$a" ]` will behave as you expect, testing the existence of a file with no name (which is false).

If `$a` has been assigned a value, then `[ -f $a ]` will check the existence of a file and `[ -z $a ]` will be false. However, I would **strongly** recommend still using double quotes in these two cases as well, to avoid problems with [word spliting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and glob expansion.

---

`-e` checks that *anything* exists (file, directory, symbolic link) whereas `-f` is more specific - it checks that a *file* exists.

Comment: fortunately, if a file is not there when a value is assigned, then it will behave differently right ?

Comment: @logan sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I asked, if a is set to any value, -z will throw false but -f will check for file presence right ? And what is -e in place of -f

Comment: Thanks. Accepted ur answer. What is symbolic link ?